# how is it possible to smoothly hide the listview footer?

Tags: android

**Background info**
My app uses a footer in the listview to show a static layout with the text "Loading more content". When a user scrolls all the way to the bottom of the listview, the "Loading more content" text becomes visible and the app makes a request to the server to fetch more data.

**Problem**
When the server has no more content, or there was a network failure, the app needs to scroll the footer out of view - how can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listview.removeFooter(footerView);`